# How to diagram tables when foreign key is nullable

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

https://i.stack.imgur.com/exoYY.jpg

I can't create this diagram relationship.  I know what's wrong and understand why.  The Route_ID in Flight Legs (left) could be null, and there's no way for Route_id to be null in the Route table (right).

But the Route_ID in FlightLeg can legitimately be null.  Maybe the user just hasn't specified a route yet.  But when it *is* specified, I want to be sure there is a related row in the routes table.  I can (and do already) ensure that the Route_ID is picked from a list of valid routes from the route table, so there is no user input error possibility.  They will always pick a valid route.  They just might NOT pick a route at all.  And that's stopping me from creating this diagram relationship.

Because of this, I know the diagram tool is right, and it means I'm going about this the wrong way.  Anyone can suggest how to make this work?

I need to allow the user to NOT specify a route, but when they do, it must be a valid route.

How do I diagram this and create the relationship?

Thanks!

edit: can't post a friggin pic without ten rep points.  Aargh!  Hope the link works.

Comment: I don't get it. Just make `route_id` nullable in the `request_flight_leg` table. (You probably should also mention the tool you are using, because this rather sounds like a tool problem, not a "SQL" problem)

Comment: I mentioned already that the Route_ID can be null in the flight legs table.  And that the problem is that it cannot be null in the Route table.  

And, the tool is plain old SSMS.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to diagram this is with a many to optional one relationship. So

```
request_flight_legs >--o route
```

The relationship means a `request_flight_legs` may have a route, in which case `request_flight_legs.route_id` will have a value. If `request_flight_legs` does not have a route (yet), `route_id` in that table will be null. it is implemented as a nullable column in the foreign key on `request_flight_legs`. In all cases `route.route_id` will always have a value. It is a not nullable column.

Is there anything preventing you doing this?

Comment: Apparently, there must be something I'm violating, even though my setup is as you suggest.  Legs.Route_ID is Nullable.  Route.Route_ID is primary key, not nullable.

Never heard of "many to optional one" relationship before, but it's exactly what I'm looking for.  Using diagram builder in SSMS.

I'm thinking there is a data violation problem that prevents this relationship from being created.

Comment: Is there a foreign key on `request_flight_legs` table? Having a look at [adding a foreign key on technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx) some questions: are both tables in the same database? Do you have the right permissions? Sorry but I'm not sure if you're creating a diagram from an existing database or create new tables using the diagram? Do you get a specific error or you just can't change the properties... so many questions :)

Comment: This error is occurring while trying to create the FK on the flight_legs table.  Basically, my foreign key can be null (record can be created without specifying a route_id, and added later) but of course, my primary key on the route table cannot be null.  I think it is this violation that prevents creation of the fk.  Can't add a possibly null fk to a definitely never null pk.

Maybe I'm looking at this wrong and there is, in fact, no relationship between the two tables such as I am imagining.

Comment: All I want is to make sure that if a route_id is entered in any flight_leg, that route_id exists in the route table.  

Maybe this is not a relationship at all?

Comment: What you want to do is basically the definition of a foreign key (or an optional foreign key to be more precise), so there is a relationship. What is the exact error message?